# Inserting JavaScript into Wordpress Posts

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

**Scenario** Its a WordPress site where users submit their projects. This goes in format of a post in WordPress. Now, they also get to fill out the description of the project which is the body of the WP post. When they edit their projects and fill out description they get a simple editor with HTML tags enabled.

**Question** I would like to monitor my project in Google Analytic . I want to insert JavaScript into that field. How do I do that ? I mean its like `<img scr...>` works fine in the box. Just when I put `<script>...</script>` the script tags are stripped out and the inner part is shown as normal text.

**Is it possible ?** I was trying to put `<img>` with source as a php file. In the php file I had had put

```
    <?php
    header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
    ?>
    <!-- Start of analytic Code -->
         analyticCode()
         {
             analytic...
             tracker.trackPageview(myCode)
         }
    <!-- Start of analytic Code -->
```

When i put this, it doesn't work at all. Nothing shows up. I went to the source and clicked the src link and it opened showing the js code.

What shall I do. I am aware of the fact this is not good but I need help.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics script need to either be put in the footer or header of your website. Or in some cases you can insert it into the body, there's nothing wrong with that!

But what you will need to do is put your Google Analytics code in the footer.php or header.php of your theme files.

So just insert it before or after your other linked css and js files. It's usually right at the top of the page by the meta tags.

Or just use this plugin and insert your script http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Comment: Sorry but I have made it clear that I have got no access to the wordpress admin and am just a normal user. I need a trick/way to insert JS into the post body field.

Comment: Oh I see, you didn't indicate if the site was yours or not. But this isn't possible unless the admin of the site allows it. There's a plugin you can install that will allow php and js in the content, but the admin needs to obviously install it.